# Filter Across Multiple Ranges Possible?

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google Sheets. I'm trying to pull information to another sheet if certain criteria  exists (equals 1, 2, etc.). The filter I'm trying to use is:

```
=filter({TestData!A5:I30,TestData!B5:B30=2},{TestData!K5:S30,TestData!L5:L30=2})
```

Is it possible to filter data across multiple locations with one formula this way?

Google Sheets gives me a formula parse error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the QUERY formula, like this:

```
=QUERY({TestData!A5:I30; TestData!K5:S30}, "SELECT * where Col2=2")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Been working through that idea for more time than I would like to admit!

Comment: @StackExchange101 you are welcome. Please mark the answer as helpful